# What's the difference between [alef-beit] and [aleph-bet-letters]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Is there a difference between these two tags, or was [alef-beit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alef-beit) just created because it's an alternate spelling and someone didn't see [aleph-bet-letters](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aleph-bet-letters)?

BTW, [hebrew-alphabet](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hebrew-alphabet) is a synonym of [aleph-bet-letters](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aleph-bet-letters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a mistake. All five instances of [alef-beit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alef-beit) should be replaced with [aleph-bet-letters](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aleph-bet-letters). Consider adding a synonym "alef-bet-letters" to prevent this from happening again the next time someone types in "alef..."